Adding a resource file to a C# project on linux
I am trying to add a resource file (a JSON schema) to my C# project. I found a lot of guides or answers to other questions that exaplain how to do that on Visual Studio Community, but on vs code the prompted menu is different, so they are not suitable for me (I am using a Linux distribution, so installing vs community is not an option). Vs code just have not got any sort of 'properties' section after right clicking on the project name or any other project/solution component.
I also tried to follow the official Microsoft guide on this topic here, but the compiler does not seem to read what is in my .resx file and prompts that "Properties is
not defined in this context"
This is my Resources.resx file:
<root>
    <data name="SchemaJson">
        <value>../Resources/Schema.json, Culture=neutral</value>
    </data>
</root>

This is my Program.cs file:
namespace sanitizzazioneLPG;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = Properties.Resources.SchemaJson;
    }
}

I also tried sanitizzazioneLPG.Properties.Resources.SchemaJson, but nothing changed.
and this is my solution organization:

EDIT: I just realized that I did not include the .csproj file. Here it is:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Gestore/" />
        <Folder Include="Persistenza/" />
        <Folder Include="Viste/" />
        <Folder Include="Properties/" />
        <Folder Include="Resources/" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" Version="3.0.15" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>


The only ""solution"" that I found is to move all the solution to a windows system, install vs community in order to add the resource and then come back to Linux.
